# Count of daily activities per machine based on a lambda conditional in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                      'machine':['A','A','A','B','B','A','B','B','A'],
                      'prod':['button','tack','pin','button','tack','pin','clip','clip','button'],
                      'qty':[100,50,30,70,60,15,200,180,np.nan],
                      'hours':[4,3,1,3,2,0.5,5,6,np.nan],
                      'day':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2]})
my_df['prod_rate']=my_df['qty']/my_df['hours']
my_df
    id  machine prod    qty     hours   day prod_rate
0   1   A       button  100.0   4.0     1   25.000000
1   2   A       tack    50.0    3.0     1   16.666667
2   3   A       pin     30.0    1.0     1   30.000000
3   4   B       button  70.0    3.0     1   23.333333
4   5   B       tack    60.0    2.0     1   30.000000
5   6   A       pin     15.0    0.5     1   30.000000
6   7   B       clip    200.0   5.0     2   40.000000
7   8   B       clip    180.0   6.0     2   30.000000
8   9   A       button  NaN     NaN     2   NaN
```

And I want to count the daily activities, except when there is a NaN (which means that the machine was paralyzed due to failure).

I tried this code:

```
my_df['activities']=my_df.groupby(['day','machine'])['machine']\
.transform(lambda x: x['machine'].count() if x['qty'].notna() else np.nan)
```

But it returns me an error: `KeyError: 'qty'`

This is the expected result:

```
id  machine prod    qty     hours   day prod_rate   activities
0   1   A   button  100.0   4.0     1   25.000000   4
1   2   A   tack    50.0    3.0     1   16.666667   4
2   3   A   pin     30.0    1.0     1   30.000000   4
3   4   B   button  70.0    3.0     1   23.333333   2
4   5   B   tack    60.0    2.0     1   30.000000   2
5   6   A   pin     15.0    0.5     1   30.000000   4
6   7   B   clip    200.0   5.0     2   40.000000   2
7   8   B   clip    180.0   6.0     2   30.000000   2
8   9   A   button  NaN     NaN     2   NaN         NaN
```

Please, could you help me fix my lambda expression? It will help me for this question and for other operations too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I prefer the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68779046/3215376) from @steele-farnsworth, here is what OP requested. for the lambda to work

```py
my_df['activities'] = my_df.groupby(['day','machine'])['qty']\
    .transform(lambda x: x.count() if x.notna().all() else np.nan)

print(my_df)
```

Prints

```
   id machine    prod    qty  hours  day  prod_rate  activities
0   1       A  button  100.0    4.0    1  25.000000         4.0
1   2       A    tack   50.0    3.0    1  16.666667         4.0
2   3       A     pin   30.0    1.0    1  30.000000         4.0
3   4       B  button   70.0    3.0    1  23.333333         2.0
4   5       B    tack   60.0    2.0    1  30.000000         2.0
5   6       A     pin   15.0    0.5    1  30.000000         4.0
6   7       B    clip  200.0    5.0    2  40.000000         2.0
7   8       B    clip  180.0    6.0    2  30.000000         2.0
8   9       A  button    NaN    NaN    2        NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Hello @tchar, I understood the idea that a vectorized solution is better than a lambda, but I was on the `x.count()` solution myself and I got stuck, fortunately your answer explains what should I do. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the calculation as normal, and then fill in the NaNs where they are wanted afterwards.

```py
>>> my_df['activities'] = my_df.groupby(['day', 'machine'])['machine'].transform('count')
>>> my_df.loc[my_df['qty'].isna(), 'activities'] = np.NaN
>>> my_df

   id machine    prod    qty  hours  day  prod_rate  activities
0   1       A  button  100.0    4.0    1  25.000000         4.0
1   2       A    tack   50.0    3.0    1  16.666667         4.0
2   3       A     pin   30.0    1.0    1  30.000000         4.0
3   4       B  button   70.0    3.0    1  23.333333         2.0
4   5       B    tack   60.0    2.0    1  30.000000         2.0
5   6       A     pin   15.0    0.5    1  30.000000         4.0
6   7       B    clip  200.0    5.0    2  40.000000         2.0
7   8       B    clip  180.0    6.0    2  30.000000         2.0
8   9       A  button    NaN    NaN    2        NaN         NaN
```

You should avoid using lambdas as much as possible in the context of Pandas, as they are not vectorized (and will therefore run slower) and are less communicative than using existing, idiomatic Pandas methods.